# Can't Execute Scripts with ./

Tags: linux, rhel, configuration

At my workplace we usually executed scripts in our linux servers with the following syntax:

```
./<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>
```

And this would normally execute the script, obviously if executed with the proper user and if had the right permissions.

Now I don't know what changed recently in the servers, the SAs administer upgrades, patches and fixes and usually provide no notification at all. The thing is that recently if we attempt to execute scripts with the same syntax, they won't run due to 'script not found'.

Our workaround has been to use the following syntax, which works:

```
bash /<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>
```

I'm not an SA or an expert on unix servers configuration, so does anyone know why this could've happened and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using an absolute path, it should have been `. /<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>` with the space to source these scripts in the currently running shell, or `/<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>` without the dot to execute the script. `./<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>` doesn't make sense.

Comment: If your scripts were previously set to be executable (`chmod u+x ./script`), it could be executed with `./script`.  If the mode of the file was set such that this is no longer so, it would no longer be so executable.  However, it would be executed with `. ./script` or `bash ./script`.

Without knowing what error you ware getting now that you had not been getting before, it is not possible to definitively state why you are seeing a change in behavior.  Please edit your question to show exactly the command you are invoking and the response the shell is providing.

Comment: The scripts are simply called directly from linux terminal, no script is invoking them at the moment. The error is that it says that the file doesn't exist in that path (which it does) when trying to execute with . /<whatever absolute path to script>/<script> and when executed with bash /<whatever absolute path to script>/<script> it find it and executes it. Executing  . /<whatever absolute path to script>/<script> worked fine up until 3 weeks ago or so, now it's not working anymore.

Comment: can you edit your post with the result of `stat ./<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>` (with leading `.` and no space between `.` and `/`), and `stat /<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>` (without leading `.` ) ?

Comment: @KrOoPine in your question you have `./` without a space, and in your comments you have `. /` with a space in between. Which is it actually?

Comment: In this case, it's best to consult those who manage the systems who will know far more about the infrastructure than anyone on the internet. It is they who are in a position to troubleshoot, let you know what's going on, and actually provide a solution that is in line with the system(s) that you are using.

Comment: In cases like this, it helps to show exactly the command you're running, and the exact error message. That is, just copypaste the relevant part from the terminal, instead of rephrasing the error message. Here, there was the question of space vs. no space, and the exact error messages can also often shed light to the real reason.

Comment: "The scripts are simply called directly from linux terminal". This is just finger trouble -- somebody has forgotten that the syntax for sourcing a script needs a space after the dot, and an absolute path name starts with a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in your examples absolute path you should use command

```
/<whatever absolute path to script>/<script>
```

w/o a dot, because in your case will mean search for relative path (dot is the current directory). With dot will work only if your current directory is `/` (root)

Also check the permissions and execution flag. Sor scripts you need to have read permission set too.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you script is executable:

  ```shell
  chmod +x <name of the script>
  ```
- Then place it your `PATH` if you want to execute it from anywhere. To find your path run:

  ```shell
  echo $PATH
  ```

Comment: All scripts are executable for the user. Should the path actually be added to $PATH to be executable this way ./ ? The path wasn't in PATH variable before and ./ worked just fine, but I will try to append it just to test. Thanks.

Comment: I would just add a file, your script that is, into the existing $PATH output. For example, it echo $PATH shows /use/local/bin drop it in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out if your script is "executable" by running `ls -l` in the directory your script exists. The output of the first column shows you the "linux permissions" for the owner, the group, or others.

You'll see "x" indicating the executable bit is set.

`-rwxr-xr-x`

There are three in this example, so the owner of the file, anyone in the owning group, and anyone else can execute the file. I found this blog entry about permission bits: https://www.linuxfoundation.org/blog/blog/classic-sysadmin-understanding-linux-file-permissions.